# java with ms access not showing database result

Tags: java, database, ms-access, database-connection

I'm trying to connect with MS-Access using java but When I Compile this code it gives me no error and compile fine but it doesn't show any result while the database has records in it, table name and field name are also correct, anyone can please help me that what I'm doing wrong in it.

```
import java.sql.*;

public class database{
Connection dbCon;
Statement statement;
ResultSet result;

public database(){
    connect();
}

public void connect(){
    try{            
        String Driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
        Class.forName(Driver);
        String Sdb = "jdbc:odbc:students";
        dbCon = DriverManager.getConnection(Sdb);
        statement = dbCon.createStatement();
        String sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM StudentInfo";
        result = statement.executeQuery(sqlQuery);

        while(result.next()) {
            //String name = result.getString("Studentname");
            System.out.println(result.getString("Studentname"));
        }
    }catch(Exception ex){

    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("**ACCESS DB CONNECTION**");
    new database();     
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not getting error during execution of program because you are eating exception here:

```
catch(Exception ex){

    }
```

You should try to print the exception trace to know what is going wrong.

```
catch(Exception ex){
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Man it really helped me to find the problem